# Postman Sending Requests based on Environment value

Tags: postman

I have an environment variable in the Request URL as https://api-{{environment}}.{{domain}}.com/api/ , how can I use them in sending requests from scripts ?
'https://api-("environment").("domain").com/api/ doesnt work , Any helps please

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the top ck sign if it hrkped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `pm.environment.get('environmentvaraiblename')` to access the value of a vaeraible inside script

you can call it within the string using string literal in java script or just concatenate using +

```
`https://api-${pm.environment.get("environment")}.${pm.environment.get("domain")}.com`
```

note that the quote is not single quote (') but (`)

Comment: Click settings and disable ssl in postman

Comment: Turn off ssl verification and give a try

Comment: Thank you so very much @PDHide it worked :) Much appreciated.

Comment: Could you accept the answer by clicking the tick sign

Comment: I did try doing that.. but getting this message. Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @uthara that's upvote , you have to accept answer by clicking the tick sign near to the answer . You can do upvote when you have 15 reputation. Now could you click the tick sign